# "ionic -v" or any command with keyword "ionic" just keeps on running. No errors or response

Tags: ionic-framework

I installed cordova and ionic through npm. When i try to check if ionic is installed correctly [through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcGRH.jpg) ionic -v command, I don't get any response. Same scenario for all commands that has  "ionic" keyword.

Comment: What does `ionic info` give you?

Comment: Did you install them globally or just in the local project?

Comment: I installed it with command "npm install -g ionic". @Dave .

Comment: "ionic info" does the same. No response or error. @praj